# GKE not capturing any application logs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

New GKE cluster has Cloud Operations for GKE set to **System and workload logging and monitoring**, however no application logs are showing up. When I inspect the installed **fluentbit-gke** in **kube-system** I'm noticing same error over and over again.

```
1server.go:47] Configured Fluent Bit GKE plugin server to run on the port 2021
server.go:139] Failed to process request: saw 1 errors; last: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
server.go:139] Failed to process request: saw 1 errors; last: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
server.go:139] Failed to process request: saw 1 errors; last: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
server.go:139] Failed to process request: saw 1 errors; last: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check that your cluster complies with the following points:

- its node-pools should have the **Stackdriver Logging API access scopes** set to "Write Only" or "Full".
- the **service account** configured at node-pool level should have the necessary **role/permissions** to contact the Stackdriver API.

Comment: Thanks! Issue was the node pool using the default service account (which no longer existed). Created a new node pool following https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#permissions