# How to get my k8s application name discovered by Google's ErrorReporting services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

I Google Cloud's ErrorReporting the "Seen in" section doesn't show anything useful for my GKE deployments. It's either empty or says `gke_instance` which is pretty useless. I have set the `serviceContext` correctly in my logs and the container name is also set in the labels of the log entries and yet it's not showing up. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve your issue try below 3 solutions :**

**Solution 1 :** If you're using Legacy Stackdriver disable it and enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring, for more information refer to the similar [Stack Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175119)

**Solution 2 :** As stated by this [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md), the stackdriver agent actually becomes disabled by default in 1.15. To activate it again you need to edit the cluster following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing). Also refer to this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077618).

**Solution 3 :** If a new GKE cluster has Cloud Operations for GKE set to System and workload logging and monitoring, however no application logs are showing up refer to this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350243).

**Note :** Issue was the node pool using the default service account (which no longer existed). Created a new node pool following the [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa).